# Access selected column from Model1 to Model2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am currently doing a project and we're using some gems such as: rails admin, devise, cancancan and ability.

I have 2 tables. ActivityItinerary and Itinerary. One of my columns in table 1 is : order, in my Itinerary, i want to call the order column in my ActivityItinerary to set a default value before it saves.

I'm having a problem regarding editing the existing itinerary, the error that gave is "Order can't be blank"

But when I create a new Activity Itinerary then try again to edit, it will work now because in my Activity Itinerary there's order field

Question: How can I get the order column from Itinerary? So that I can set a default value for that column

EDITED

NOTE: I tried to use the pluck to get the order column in my ActivityItinerary

Question: Why it doesn't add a default value for my order column in activityItinerary?

**table 2/table 2 model**

```
class Itinerary < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :created_by
  belongs_to :activity
  before_save :default_value, :count_all_activity
  after_save
  # has_many :activity_itineraries, foreign_key: :created_by
  has_many :activity_itineraries, inverse_of: :itinerary
  has_many :activities, through: :activity_itineraries

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :no_of_days, presence: true,
               :numericality => true
```

UPDATE:

I've done the first part which is adding a default value of order before it will save. Here is my updated file.

NOTE: I am having an error undefined method `count' for 1:Integer.

**Activity Itinerary**

```
class ActivityItinerary < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :itinerary, inverse_of: :activity_itineraries
  belongs_to :activity, inverse_of: :activity_itineraries

  before_save :count_all_activity_itinerary

  validates :order, presence: true
  validates :activity_id, presence: true

  after_initialize :set_defaults, unless: :persisted?

  private 

  def set_defaults
    self.order ||= 1 # 
  end

  def count_all_activity_itinerary
    order.count(:conditions => itinerary.id)
  end

end
```

Another question: How can I count all the activityitineraries where itinerary_id. What is the cause of this error?

Comment: What is relation between these models? What do you mean about 'call order column' ? You have `order` column in table 1 and want to do something in table 2 with `order` column from table 1 in `before_save` callback?

Comment: Please provide a code where this error occurs.

Comment: I talked about code which you executed and then this error occurs.

Comment: Don't know too, because as I mention above it gives me this error whenever I tried to edit

Comment: Yeah, what do you exactly mean under 'edit'? Of course you try to execute some code, so please provide full example how error occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145849/discussion-between-angel-and-djezzzl).